# How do you protect next-auth custom verify / error pages from being accessed directly?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth for authentication along with the email provider. The user enters their email address on `/` and clicks sign in, a /pages/auth/verify `localhost:3000/auth/verify` page loads to tell them to check their email for a link.

Currently I can access the page directly without signing in by going to `localhost:3000/auth/verify` and it shows the contents.

The same for `localhost:3000/auth/error` since they can be loaded directly.

How do I protect these pages from loading unless it's part of the next-auth workflow, as in they only load if being called from signIn() maybe? This is my first time working with nextJS and next-auth in general.

pages/auth/verify.tsx

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Box, Flex, Heading, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { CheckCircleIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function Verify() {
  //const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Flex minH={'100vh'} align={'center'} justify={'center'}>
        <Box textAlign="center" py={10} px={6} maxW={'500'}>
          <CheckCircleIcon boxSize={'50px'} color={'green.500'} />
          <Heading as="h2" size="xl" mt={6} mb={2}>
            Check Your Email
          </Heading>
          <Text color={'gray.500'}>
            A verification email has been sent to your email address. Please
            check your inbox and click the link to verify your email address.
          </Text>
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I tried utilizing the useSession() function for checking status but it only provides `loading` `authenticated` `unauthenticated` which loading would be just for the page load , authenticated isn't true since they need to check their email and unauthenticated would be the same and not using anything like it is now.

I need to only show the page if they have started the signIn() process in next-auth.

Would love to have some guidance on this as maybe I'm handling this incorrectly.

Should I keep everything on the login page and just swap components based on the steps? I can't find any tutorials on that process though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can think of is to check from where the `Verify` page was called using `getServerSideProps` since the function is called on every request.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const willMount = context.req.headers.referer === "http://localhost:3000/example";
  if (!willMount) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/404",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

The code checks if the page was not called from `"http://localhost:3000/example"` so it redirects the user to the `/404` url

Note: the property `refer` will no exist in `context.req.headers` if the user enters the `URL` manually so you can check this way too :

```
if (!context.req.headers.referer)
```

but the first allows you to specify the URLs that you want to accept.

maybe you are using nextjs 13.2 with the app dir where `getServerSide` props is deprecated

> Good to know: Previous Next.js data fetching methods such as getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, and getInitialProps are not supported in the new app directory.

so take a look [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals) and find an alternative now you got the main idea.